# assignment of arrays to pointers in C

Tags: c

Fragment 1:

```
char** x;
char arr[][4] = {"abc","def"};
x = arr;                             // why is this wrong ? but;
```

Fragment 2:

```
char* x;
char arr[4] = {"def"};
x = arr;                             // this is correct
```

So how can we assign 2d array to a double pointer (also for any multidimensional arrays)?

Also, I have a struct and I want to make an assignment as follows:

```
struct document
{
    char **text;
    int numOfLines;
};

char arr[3][50] = {
    "IF WE COULD TAKE THE TIME",
    "TO LAY IT ON THE LINE",
    "I COULD REST MY HEAD" };
t->text = arr;                           // I think it is the same problem
```

but can we directly assign a double pointer as:

```
t->text = { "IF WE COULD TAKE THE TIME", "TO LAY IT ON THE LINE", "I COULD REST MY HEAD" };
```

Also why does this work:

```
char *arr[3] = {
    "IF WE COULD TAKE THE TIME",
    "TO LAY IT ON THE LINE",
    "I COULD REST MY HEAD" };
t->text = arr;
```

Comment: In the first fragment, `arr` has the type `char (*)[4]` — pointer to an array of 4 characters — which is quite different from `char **`, which is why the compiler complains about the assignment.

Comment: A C array is several objects in consecutive memory locations. So a two-dimensional array is several one-dimensional arrays in consecutive memory locations. It just *isn't* a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: possible duplicate [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function)

Comment: Does the `t->text = { …three string literals… };` fragment compile?  It shouldn't.  You'd need to use the compound literal notation: `t->text = (char *[]){ …three string literals… };`.

Comment: it is wrong ,but the last  part is correct

Comment: how can we assign 2d array to a double pointer?

Comment: You can't (assign a 2D array to a pointer to pointer) — they are not compatible types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Statement `char **x;` means pointer to pointer, but `char arr[][4];` is somehow pointer to array.
Code below works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{   
    char (*x)[10];
    char arr1[][10] = {{"First"}, {"Second"}};
    x = arr1;
    printf("%s\n%s\n", arr1[0], arr1[1]);
    printf("%s\n%s\n", x[0], x[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are declarations of  char (*x)[10]; and char arr1[][10]; are equivalent?

Comment: You cannot static allocate various size array, `char arr[][4] = {{"abc"}, {"cba"}};` is translated to `char arr[2][4] = {{"abc"}, {"cba"}};`, but `char (*x)[4];` (because it is pointer) can be assigned to every array with unknown first dimension.

Answer (score 1):

## Question 1

`char arr[][4] = {"abc","def"};` defines `arr` to be an array of arrays. With other objects, such as a structure, one structure, say `C`, could be assigned to another structure, say `B`, of the same type, using `B = C;`. However, C has special rules for arrays.

When an array is used in an expression, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, except when it is the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&` or is a string literal used to initialize an array. So, when we write:

```
x = arr;
```

the automatic conversion makes it as if we had written:

```
x = &arr[0];
```

Then, since `&arr[0]` is a pointer to an array of 4 `char`, `x` must also be a pointer to an array of 4 `char` (or something compatible, perhaps a pointer to an array of an unknown number of `char`).

Note that `char **x;` declares a pointer to a pointer. That is, it is a pointer, and, at the memory it points to, there must be another pointer. In contrast, `&arr[0]` is a pointer to an array. It is a pointer, and, at the memory it points to, there is an array of 4 `char`. If you tried to use `**x`, the compiler would look at the memory that `x` points to and expect to find a pointer there. If, instead, there is not a pointer but rather four arbitrary `char` values, the program would be broken. So `char **x` is not compatible with a pointer to an array of 4 `char`.

A proper declaration for `x` would be `char (*x)[4];`. After such a declaration, the assignment `x = arr;` would be proper.

## Question 2

Your code `t->text = { "IF WE COULD TAKE THE TIME", "TO LAY IT ON THE LINE", "I COULD REST MY HEAD" };` is not strictly conforming C and does not compile in typical compilers.

## Question 3

Consider the code (adjusted to allow compilation):

```
struct document
{
    char **text;
    int numOfLines;
} t;

char *arr[3] = {
    "IF WE COULD TAKE THE TIME",
    "TO LAY IT ON THE LINE",
    "I COULD REST MY HEAD" };
t.text = arr;
```

`char *arr[3]` declares `arr` to be an array of 3 pointers to `char`. It is then initialized to contain three pointers to (the first characters of) strings.

So each element of `arr`, `arr[i]` is a pointer to `char`. By C’s rule about automatic conversion of arrays, in `t.text = arr;`, `arr` is converted to a pointer to its first element. So we have `t.text = &arr[0];`. Then `&arr[0]` is a pointer to a pointer to a `char`, and `t.text` is a pointer to a pointer to a `char`, so the types are compatible.